# SQL - Update in a cross apply query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

```
UPDATE Table1
SET SomeColumn = X.SomeOtherColumn
FROM Table1 T1
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 SomeOtherColumn 
     FROM Table2 T2 
     WHERE T2.SomeJoinColumn = T1.SomeJoinColumn 
     ORDER BY CounterColumn) AS X
```

I want to increase `CounterColumn` by 1 each time the `cross apply` query runs. Is there any way I could achieve this?

**Some context and sample data**

I have a table containing information about companies. I want to anonymize the company numbers in this table. To do this, I want to use data from another table, containing synthetized data. This table has a much smaller sample size. So I have to reuse the same synthetic companies multiple times. For each row in the table I anonymize, I want to pick a synthetic company of the same type. I want to use all the synthetic companies. That's where the *counter* comes in, counting how many times I've used that specific synthetic company. By sorting by this counter, I was hoping to be able to always pick the synthetic company that's been used the least.

Company table (Table1)

| CompanyNumber | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 67923 | 2 |
| 82034 | 2 |
| 90238 | 7 |
| 29378 | 2 |
| 92809 | 5 |
| 72890 | 2 |

Synthetic company table (Table2)

| SyntheticCompanyNumber | Type | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08366 | 5 | 0 |
| 12588 | 2 | 0 |
| 33823 | 2 | 0 |
| 27483 | 7 | 0 |

Expected output of Company table:

| CompanyNumber | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 12588 | 2 |
| 33823 | 2 |
| 27483 | 7 |
| 12588 | 2 |
| 08366 | 5 |
| 33823 | 2 |

Expected output of synthetic company table

| SynteticCompanyNumber | Type | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08366 | 5 | 1 |
| 12588 | 2 | 2 |
| 33823 | 2 | 2 |
| 27483 | 7 | 1 |

Comment: Can you edit tags and add what kind of database (SQL Server? Oracle). What is the input and expected output when you run this query? `CounterColumn` will never change in this query as it is never updated. You should also consider what you want to happen if two different connections run this at the same time.

Comment: `row_number()`?

Comment: I added a SQL Server tag. I don't know how to update the _CounterColumn_ inside the cross apply. That's what I'm trying to figure out. In my case, there will never be multiple connections running this at the same time.

Comment: "there will never be multiple connections" - that is not the kind of assumption you want to make as who knows what the future will bring. You should always write defensive code that can cope with all possibilities.

Comment: The easy way would be to add a column to Table1, store what value of CounterColumn, and update-increment Table2. The hard way would be to use `merge` and `output` to keep the value.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would help immensely. It's unclear what you mean "increase CounterColumn by 1 each time the cross apply query runs" the `cross apply` doesn't *run* it is applied to each outer row, and the meaning "increase" in the context of `ORDER BY CounterColumn` is also unclear

Comment: After each time the `cross apply`  is applied to the outer row, I want to update the `CounterColumn` - `CounterColumn = CounterColumn + 1`  - in the row from Table2 from the inner query.